# Proper Qt data structure for storing and accessing struct pointers

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, struct, hashtable

I have a certain struct:

```
struct MyClass::MyStruct
{
    Statistics stats;
    Oject *objPtr;
    bool isActive;
    QDateTime expiration;
};
```

For which I need to store pointers to in a private container.  I will be getting objects from client code for which I need to return a pointer to the `MyStruct`.  For example:

```
QList<MyStruct*> MyClass::structPtr( Statistics stats )
{
    // Return all MyStruct* for which myStruct->stats == stats (== is overloaded)
}
```

or

```
QList<MyStruct*> MyClass::structPtr( Object *objPtr )
{
    // Return all MyStruct* for which myStruct->objPtr == objPtr
}
```

Right now I'm storing these in a `QLinkedList<MyStruct*>` so that I can have fast insertions, and lookups roughly equivalent to `QList<MyStruct*>`.  Ideally I would like to be able to perform lookups faster, without losing my insertion speed.  This leads me to look at `QHash`, but I am not sure how I would use a `QHash` when I'm only storing values without  keys, or even if that is a good idea.

What is the proper Qt/C++ way to address a problem such as this?  Ideally, lookup times should be `<= log(n)`.  Would a `QHash` be a good idea here?  If so, what should I use for a key and/or value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with only looking up your data in one specific way, a `QHash` should be fine for you.  Though, in your case where you're pulling lists out, you may want to investigate `QMultiHash` and its `.values()` member.  However, it's important to note, from the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qhash.html#details):

> The key type of a QHash must provide operator==() and a global hash function called qHash()

If you need to be able to pull these lists based on different information at different times you might just be better off iterating over the lists. All of Qt's containers provide std-style iterators, including its hash maps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `QHash` for fast lookups, the hash's key type must be the same as the search token type. For example, if you want to find elements by `Statistics` value, your hash should be `QHash<Statistics, MyStruct*>`.

Comment: Is it expensive if I use `QHash<Statistic, MyStruct*>`, and then call `hash.values()` when I need to iterate the list?

Comment: I think the fastest way to iterate through all objects is using iterator that can be obtained from `begin()`.

Comment: I'm going to accept the other answer because I think it's a bit more helpful, but +1 for some good advice.  Thanks!